# String created by JSON.stringify creates error when eval'd by JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

I am passing a string created by JSON.stringify as a argument to another function that evals it via JSON.parse however the parse function is generating an error.

The JSON being stringified is a portion of a JSON object created by  from the Xero API (the accounting package) through Service_JSON (a PHP pear package) - it validates fine.

JSON.parse seems to error on any ' characters.

Question 1: Does stringify not escape special characters like new lines and single quotes?

Question 2: Shouldn't I expect that a JSON.stringifyed string generated without error would be parsed without error in JSON.parse since they are the complimenting/opposite functions of each other?

EDIT:

Heaviliy redacted code as follows:

```
function PANDA_INVOICING_JS_save_invoice_add(theWindowID,loadPopupFrom) {
  var theForm = $('#'+theWindowID+'_form');
  var theFrameID = Date.parse(new Date());
  $.ajax({
    url:          '?module=invoicing&action=save_invoices_add&window_uid='+theWindowID,
    method:       'post',
    data:         theForm.serialize(),
  }).done(function(result) {
    var theJSON = result;
      if (loadPopupFrom) {
        var theURL = '?module=invoicing&action=display_invoices_details&invoice_id='+theInvoiceID+'&loadfrom='+loadPopupFrom+'&window_uid='+theFrameID;
      } else {
        var theURL = '?module=invoicing&action=display_invoices_details&invoice_id='+theInvoiceID;
      }
      /**
       * XERO Allocate Credit
       */
      var loadfunctions = false;
      if (APP_JS_check_nestedobjects(theJSON,'data','xero_data','response')) {
        if ($.isNumeric(theJSON.data.xero_data.credits.availablecredit) && theJSON.data.xero_data.credits.availablecredit > 0) {
          var theXEROdata = JSON.stringify(theJSON.data.xero_data);
          var loadfunctions = [
            {
              functionname:     'PANDA_PLUGIN_JS_xero_credit_notify',
              'arguments':      '####__WINDOWID__####,\''+theXEROdata+'\',\''+theURL+'\''
            }
          ];
        }
      }
      /* Load the new invoice */
      APP_JS_frame((loadPopupFrom) ? true : false, theURL,loadfunctions);
    }
  });
  /**
   * Return true
   */
    return true;
}
```

Passes through to this code in APP_JS_frame ( yes: the eval is a evil but necessary in this case and no user data is eval'd):

```
if (typeof(loadfunctions)=='object') {
  for (i=0;i<loadfunctions.length;i++) {
    if (! loadfunctions[i].functionname) continue; //if functionname is not defined move on
    if (loadfunctions[i].arguments) {
      arguments = $PHP_JS.str_replace('####__WINDOWID__####',theFrameID,loadfunctions[i].arguments)
    } else {
      arguments = '';
    }
    eval(loadfunctions[i].functionname + '('+arguments+')');
  }
}
```

Then through to this function where the error is actually thrown:

```
function PANDA_PLUGIN_JS_xero_credit_notify(theFrameID, theXerodata, theURL) {
      /* Parse JSON and set variables */
      theXerodata = theXerodata.escapeJSON();
      theXerodata = JSON.parse(theXerodata);
```

}

escapeJSON() is as follows:

```
String.prototype.escapeJSON = function() {
  return this.replace(/[\\]/g, '\\\\')
    .replace(/[\b]/g, '\\b')
    .replace(/[\f]/g, '\\f')
    .replace(/[\n]/g, '\\n')
    .replace(/[\r]/g, '\\r')
    .replace(/[\t]/g, '\\t')
    .replace(/[']/g, "\\'");
};
```

As for the actual xeroData string - it should matter what it is - as JSON.stringify should generate valid JSON for JSON.parse to use - right? But for data sake here is the JSON:

```
{
    "xero_data": {
        "invoices": {
            "invoice_id": "4323",
            "invoice_balance": "123.00",
            "date_invoice": "2016-11-20",
            "contact_id": "2558",
            "contact_name": "Person, Test"
        },
        "response": {
            "return_code": 200,
            "xero_response": {
                "Id": "dedb737c-ce42-433f-aa2b-02478b839bbf",
                "Status": "OK",
                "ProviderName": "PANDA-Developer",
                "DateTimeUTC": "2016-11-19T23:28:28.6858694Z",
                "Invoices": {
                    "Invoice": {
                        "Contact": {
                            "ContactID": "b1e95873-81b2-44f6-b46a-3d4df44ef602",
                            "ContactStatus": "ACTIVE",
                            "Name": "Test Person",
                            "FirstName": "Test",
                            "LastName": "Person",
                            "EmailAddress": "emailaddress",
                            "Addresses": {
                                "Address": [{
                                    "AddressType": "STREET"
                                }, {
                                    "AddressType": "POBOX",
                                    "AddressLine1": "P.O. Box",
                                    "City": "Town",
                                    "Region": "Otago",
                                    "PostalCode": "1201",
                                    "Country": "New Zealand"
                                }]
                            },
                            "Phones": {
                                "Phone": [{
                                    "PhoneType": "DEFAULT"
                                }, {
                                    "PhoneType": "DDI"
                                }, {
                                    "PhoneType": "FAX"
                                }, {
                                    "PhoneType": "MOBILE"
                                }]
                            },
                            "UpdatedDateUTC": "2016-11-19T02:49:47.58",
                            "IsSupplier": "false",
                            "IsCustomer": "true"
                        },
                        "Date": "2016-11-20T00:00:00",
                        "DueDate": "2016-11-30T00:00:00",
                        "ExpectedPaymentDate": "2016-11-30T00:00:00",
                        "Status": "AUTHORISED",
                        "LineAmountTypes": "Inclusive",
                        "LineItems": {
                            "LineItem": {
                                "Description": "Test Data '\n              \n              - new line\n              - new line",
                                "UnitAmount": "123.00",
                                "TaxType": "OUTPUT2",
                                "TaxAmount": "16.04",
                                "LineAmount": "123.00",
                                "AccountCode": "260",
                                "Quantity": "1.0000",
                                "DiscountRate": "0.00",
                                "LineItemID": "a4c2da16-4d94-42d6-ae37-e3091901b79b"
                            }
                        },
                        "SubTotal": "106.96",
                        "TotalTax": "16.04",
                        "Total": "123.00",
                        "UpdatedDateUTC": "2016-11-19T23:28:28.607",
                        "CurrencyCode": "NZD",
                        "Type": "ACCREC",
                        "InvoiceID": "cdb5b8e9-afac-4f72-b74b-d9b292295c34",
                        "InvoiceNumber": "PANDA4323",
                        "Reference": "test 34",
                        "AmountDue": "123.00",
                        "AmountPaid": "0.00",
                        "SentToContact": "false",
                        "CurrencyRate": "1.000000",
                        "TotalDiscount": "0.00"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "credits": {
            "0": {
                "Type": "creditnote",
                "UUID": "345d423e-58a6-4e05-8ae5-33da4e886bb9",
                "CreditNoteNumber": "CN-0041",
                "RemainingCredit": 182.65
            },
            "availablecredit": 182.65
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not really possible to answer this without either access to xero software or your actual JSON. I wouldn't give too much credit to a PHP package validation. Try http://jsonlint.com/ as a second opinion, too.

Comment: Can you share the example object / string?

Comment: 1 - JSON.stringify generates valid JSON or throws trying. 2 - yes, that is always the case. there's something else going on in your code you're not sharing, or that you don't understand

Comment: `theXerodata.escapeJSON();` - you do that before doing `JSON.parse` - why do you claim it's `JSON.stringify`'s fault?

Comment: Can you post the original `json` data before `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: @vlaz Commenting out `theXerodata.escapeJSON();` still generates the error at JSON.parse

Comment: Doing `stringify` followed by `parse` with the object supplied worls. Doing the `escapeJSON` between the two, doesn't.

Comment: When the LineItem->Description has no newlines it processes without error however the following generate different errors: newlines in the description gives `JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 1128 of the JSON data` and with a `'` in the description it gives `SyntaxError: illegal character`

Comment: @vlaz unfortunately I think the object supplied above (which was copied from console.log(xeroData)) is fixed by console - not sure how to get the raw data as alert(xeroData) gives [Obj Obj]

Comment: I have managed to load the data into https://jsfiddle.net/3o0zewh9/2/ which gives the same errors I am getting in my application

Comment: In your fiddle, you have actual newlines (`\n`), where you should have a newline escape sequence. If you are entering the JSON data as Javascript source (rather than loading it via XHR for instance), you need to escape those: `\\n`, so that JS interprets them as `\ ` + `n` sequences, which will then be decoded by `JSON.parse`.